# PowerShell Native Cmdlet Set-Alias with Function and Switch

Tags: powershell

**Question:**
Is it possible to set an alias that calls both a function and a switch?

Here is an example I am working with.

```
Set-Alias -Name myidea -Value 'Test-FunctionIdea -SwitchIdea' 
function Test-FunctionIdea {
  param(
    [switch]$SwitchIdea
  )
  if($SwitchIdea)
  {
    Write-Host 'Good Idea'
  }
}
```

Here is the error I am having:

```
myidea : The term 'Test-FunctionIdea -SwitchIdea' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if 
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ myidea
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Test-FunctionIdea -SwitchIdea:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

If it is possible please let me know how it's done. I've searched the internet for this and came up with no results.

Comment: `function myidea { Test-FunctionIdea -SwitchIdea }`. 
*"In Bash, the recommendation is that “for almost every purpose, shell functions are preferred over aliases” ... and that recommendation is even stronger for PowerShell. The PowerShell “alias” is a true alias — it’s just another name for a command, script, function, etc. and it doesn’t support passing parameters or making mini-scripts at all."* -  https://web.archive.org/web/20120213013609/http://huddledmasses.org/powershell-power-user-tips-bash-style-alias-command

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler thank you! Works like a charm, do you want to answer the question so I can give you proper credit?

Answer (score 3):

You can check `$MyInvocation.InvocationName` and adjust the parameters inside the function:

```
function Some-Function([switch] $foo) {
     if ($MyInvocation.InvocationName -eq 'foo') { $foo = $true }
}

Set-Alias foo Some-Function
```

The [usually negligible] advantage is that it doesn't create an additional execution context for the new function scope.

Comment: I would never use that in production code but +1 for an interesting approach!